# SQL Query - Join

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a Table which contains student information(name, id, course,....), and I have another table which contains information like(id, student leave)

I need to generate a report, which is by course all the students who were absent....

Am confused on how to do this properly - Do i use an outer join or what cause SQL 5.0 keeps giving me errors like syntax error....

Have to use this query in servlets...!!!

Currently am using the query in 2 parts.... but which is not generating the table properly....

Comment: Also give more details on your data structure, especially the data types and how you determine whether a student is absent.

Comment: Select * From Student Where course_id="ENG"
Executing that query

Select * From Attendance where student_id=<The retieved id>
Sorry my sql skills aew very limited....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Student s LEFT JOIN Attendance a ON a.student_id = s.id WHERE s.course_id = "ENG"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From Student s left join Attendance a on a.student_id = s.id where course_id='ENG'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student s, Attendance a
WHERE s.id = a.student_id
AND s.course_id = "ENG"
AND s.id = <the_retrieved_id>
```

Should also be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turning Student.id to Student.student_id to make it clear,
and also use integer for keys in course table.
then use join like [Pradeep Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400706/sql-query-join/4400875#4400875) only with "using":

```
select * from Student s left join Attendance a using (student_id) where s.course_id="ENG"
```